# Why an Rvalue Reference is Turned into Lvalue Reference by a Universal Reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding, lvalue-to-rvalue

I suppose when a universal reference parameter is matched with an rvalue reference argument, an rvalue reference argument is returned. However, my testing shows that the rvalue reference is turned into a lvalue reference by the universal reference function template. Why is it so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
T f1(T&&t) {  //<-----this is a universal reference
  cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << endl;
  cout << "is_rvalue reference:" << is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << endl;
  cout << "is_reference:"        << is_reference<T>::value        << endl;
  return t;
}
void f2(int&& t) {
  cout << "f2 is_lvalue reference:" << is_lvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << endl;
  cout << "f2 is_rvalue reference:" << is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << endl;
  cout << "f2 is_reference:" << is_reference<decltype(t)>::value << endl;
  f1(t);

}

int main()
{
  f2(5);
  return 0;
}
```

In both GCC and VC++2010, this is the result:

```
f2 is_lvalue reference:0
f2 is_rvalue reference:1
f2 is_reference:1
is_lvalue reference:1
is_rvalue reference:0
is_reference:1
```

In other words, the parameter `t` in `f2` was an rvalue reference, but when passed to `f1`, the parameter became a lvalue reference. Shouldn't it retain the rvalue-ness in `f1`?

Comment: No, it's the reason we need `std::forward`

Comment: what are the specific rules related to universal reference? Scott Meyers, in his book,  just said rvalue to rvalue reference, lvalue to lvalue reference

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Answer (score 9):

The reason is that named rvalue references are treated as lvalues.

You should use [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) inside *f2* when passing *t* to *f1* to retain rvalueness:

```
void f2(int&& t) {
    f1(std::move(t));
}
```

[Here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html) you can find a good explanation.

Comment: The link which you shared has an example at the very last `Derived(Derived&& rhs) 
  : Base(std::move(rhs)) // good, calls Base(Base&& rhs)
{
  // Derived-specific stuff
}`. Now, suppose `class Derived` had data_member `int x;`. Please specify how rhs can now be used in assignment `this->x=rhs.x`. Since its a copy constructor so, `Derived` data needs to copied from the `rhs` to `this`.But since `rhs` is `move`d so, i guess it will not be valid to use it any more.

Comment: ok, std::move() casts its argument to rvalue. But what is the type of the rvalue formed by this expression `std::move(t)`? rvalue of type `int&&` or rvalue of type `int`?

Comment: @JavaMan rvalue of type `int`. Only expressions have value categories, and expressions cannot have reference types.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `f1(t)`,  the argument is the expression `t`. Not `static_cast<decltype(t)>(t)` or something. Your examination of `decltype(t)` has nothing to do with the call of `f1(t)`.

The expression `t` has type `int` and value category *lvalue*. (A rule of thumb is that if you can take the address of an expression then it is an lvalue, and you can certainly write `&t`). The "information" that a reference variable was originally declared as a reference is only visible via a `decltype` examination.

Since `f1` is called with an lvalue, `T` is deduced to `int&`.

NB. You possibly want `f1` to also use `decltype(t)` rather than `T`, if you ever want to see `is_rvalue_reference` being true in `f1`. For rvalue arguments, `T` deduces to a non-reference type, e.g. if you fix `f2` by making it do `f1(std::move(t));` then `f1`'s `T` is `int` and `decltype(t)` in `f1` is `int&&`.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the C++11 standard, I have a vague idea on what was going on after my `f1(t);` in `f2`. I describe it here to see if I got it right:

1. In `f2`, `t` is an lvalue of type `int&&` (not `int`, this is an important difference)
2. the call `f1(t);` causes type to be deduced like this:

   2.1 when `T` in `f1` is given an lvalue, it is deduced as a reference of that lvalue's type or`int&& &`

   2.2 reference collapsing causes `int&& &` to become `int &`. This is the value of `T`.
3. Since the parameter of `f1` is declared as `T&&`, the type of parameter `t` in `f1` is `int & &&`. So reference collapsing occurs a second time to deduce the type of `t` as `int &`.
4. Hence T=`int &` and type of parameter `t` is `int &`. i.e. parameter `t` is an lvalue of type `int &`

Any comment?

Comment: There is no reference collapsing in step 2. The type of the _variable_ `t` is `int&&`, while the type of the _expression_ `t` is `int`. This is just how references work and have always worked, regardless of value category, even before rvalue references were added to the language.

Comment: in that case, what is the value of `T` in step 2? Shouldn't it be `int&& &` instead of `int &`? If T is `int&& &`, isn't that we have to collapse it to get the parameter type?

Comment: `T` is not involved in step 2. `f1` is called with an lvalue expression of type `int`, so in step 3, `T` is deduced as `int&`, so `T&&` is `int& &&` which collapses to `int&`.

Answer (score -1):

use the std::forward to keep t as rvalue.

```
void f2(int&& t) {
  //....
  f1(std::forward<int>(t));
}
```

The t argument is passed as rvalue and deduced as type int. (see how the deduction is done [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) )

std::forward(t) returns a rvalue of type int&& so that calls f1(int&&)

without std::forward(t), f1(t) takes the argument of type int and calls f1(int&)

**UPDATE:** Please be aware of the difference between

```
 is_lvalue_reference<T> and is_lvalue_reference<decltype<t>>.
```

In the template, T is deduced based on the function argument, whereas the value category of t is always lvalue in f2 and

```
forward<int>(t) and move(t)
```

are always rvalue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};


template <typename T>
T f0(T& t) {  //<-----this is a universal reference
    std::cout<< "f0 lvalue"<<'\n';

    // take T as template argument, it is type int, so not rvalue, not lvalue.
//  std::cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_rvalue reference:" << std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_reference:"        << std::is_reference<T>::value        << std::endl;
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
T f0(T&&t) {  //<-----this is a universal reference
    std::cout<< "f0 rvalue"<<'\n';
    std::cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_rvalue reference:" << std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_reference:"        << std::is_reference<T>::value        << std::endl;
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
T f1(T& t) {  //<-----this is a universal reference
    std::cout<< "f1 lvalue"<<'\n';

    // take T as template argument, it is type int, so not rvalue, not lvalue.
//  std::cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_rvalue reference:" << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_reference:"        << std::is_reference<decltype(t)>::value        << std::endl;
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
T f1(T&&t) {  //<-----this is a universal reference
    std::cout<< "f1 rvalue"<<'\n';
    std::cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_rvalue reference:" << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_reference:"        << std::is_reference<decltype(t)>::value        << std::endl;
    return t;
}

void f2(int&&t) {  //<-----this is a universal reference
    std::cout<< "f2 rvalue"<<'\n';
    std::cout << "is_lvalue reference:" << std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_rvalue reference:" << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_reference:"        << std::is_reference<decltype(t)>::value        << std::endl;


    f1(std::forward<int>(t));   // T is deduced as int for f(T&&), type int is not rvalue, nor lvalue, t is rvalue
    f1(std::move(t));           // T is deduced as int for f(T&&), type int is not rvalue, nor lvalue, t is rvalue
    f1(t);                      // T is deduced as int for f(T&),  type int is not rvalue, nor lvalue, t is lvalue
                                //if f1(T&) not exist, then f1(t) will call f1(T&&), T is deduced as int&, type int& is lvalue, t is lvalue


    f0(std::forward<int>(t));   // T is deduced as int for f(T&&), type int is not rvalue, nor lvalue, t is rvalue
    f0(std::move(t));           // T is deduced as int for f(T&&), type int is not rvalue, nor lvalue, t is rvalue
    f0(t);                      // T is deduced as int for f(T&),  type int is not rvalue, nor lvalue, t is lvalue
                                //if f0(T&) not exist, then f0(t) will call f0(T&&), T is deduced as int&, type int& is lvalue, t is lvalue
}




void test_rvalue()
{

    f2(5);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_lvalue_reference<A>::value << '\n';        // A is not lvalue
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<A>::value << '\n';        // A is not rvalue
    std::cout << std::is_lvalue_reference<A&>::value << '\n';       // A& is lvalue
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<A&&>::value << '\n';      // A&& is rvalue
    std::cout << std::is_lvalue_reference<int>::value << '\n';      // int is not lvalue
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<int>::value << '\n';      // int is not rvalue
    std::cout << std::is_lvalue_reference<int&>::value << '\n';     // int& is lvalue
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<int&&>::value << '\n';    // int&& is rvalue

}
```