# C++11: Why rvalue reference parameter implicitly converted to lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Following is the simplistic code of my problem,

```
void overloaded (int&& x) {
  cout << "[rvalue]";
}

template <class T>
void fn (T&& x) {
  overloaded(x);
}

int main() {
    fn(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I got a compile error

> cannot bind ‘`int`’ lvalue to ‘`int&&`’
>
> ```
>   overloaded(x);
> ```

I am confused here, `x` is passed as a rvalue reference into `fn()`. But why the `overload()` call in `fn()` complains `x` is a lvalue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One, the `x` argument to `fn` isn't an r-value reference, [it's a "universal reference"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41360880/364696) (yes, [this is rather confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20364297/364696)).

Two, the moment you give an object a name, that name is not an r-value unless explicitly "fixed", either with `std::move` (to make it an r-value reference, always), or with `std::forward` (to convert it back to its original type in the case of universal references). If you want to avoid the complaint, use `std::forward` to forward as the original type:

```
template <class T>
void fn (T&& x) {
  overloaded(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

Comment: " the moment you name a variable, it stops being an r-value" doesn't make sense. An rvalue is an expression category, not a variable or object. An object does not have an expression category;  it is expressions referring to that variable which have expression categories, and the same object can have different categories of expression referring to it

Comment: @M.M: I'd welcome more accurate wording that doesn't require one to fully grok the C++ spec to understand it. The point is, as soon as you bind an r-value to a name (even a named declared as `&&`) it can't be used as an r-value without additional "effort" (`std::move`/`std::forward`). Would you prefer "The moment you give an object a name, it stops being an r-value"?

Comment: Objects are never lvalues or rvalues at any point.  The expression denoting an object could be an lvalue or an rvalue.  Binding a reference to an object does not change any of the properties of the object (other than perhaps extending its lifetime). The name `x` *is* an lvalue; it doesn't become one, and the object given as argument doesn't "stop being an rvalue" because it never was an rvalue, it was (and still is) an object

Comment: Re. the most recent edit, `x` is always an lvalue, there is no "unless". Code like `std::forward<T>(x)` is a different expression than `x`. The whole paragraph talks as if the actual object has the property of being an lvalue or rvalue.

Answer (score 8):

You're not "passing `x` as an rvalue reference", since that statement doesn't even really make sense.

Here are a selection of facts about the taxonomy of types and expressions in C++:

- There are object types and there are reference types. (There are also a few other kinds of types.)
- Variables can be either objects or references.
- Expressions have types, those types are (almost) always object types, never references. (That's why your statement of "passing something as a reference" doesn't make sense; you pass *arguments* and arguments are always expressions.) Expressions can be lvalues, xvalues or prvalues.
- Lvalue references bind to lvalues. Rvalue references bind to rvalues. (An rvalue is either a prvalue or an xvalue.)
- An id-expression naming a variable or parameter is an lvalue. (It's a "thing with a name", or "a location", if you will.)

Hence in the expression `overloaded(x)`, the subexpression `x` is an lvalue, and it does not bind to the function that expects an rvalue (on account of its rvalue reference parameter).

The "l" and "r" in "lvalue reference" and "rvalue reference" refers to the categories of values to which the reference can bind, *not* to the category of the id-expression naming a variable of this reference type.

You can convert an lvalue to an rvalue by casting it to an xvalue; this is conveniently encapsulated into the type-deducing cast helper `std::move`.