# C++ universal references. Why rvalue reference becomes lvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue, type-deduction

Here's the code that troubles me

```
‍‍‍‍‍#include <iostream>

#include "DataItem.h"


void testRef( const int & param )
{
    std::cout << "Lvalue reference" << std::endl;
}

void testRef( int && param )
{
    std::cout << "Rvalue reference" << std::endl;

    // Here's the thing I can't get. Why param is lvalue reference here??
    testRef( param );
}


template<class T>
void func( T && param )
{
    testRef( std::forward<T>( param ) );
}


int main2() 
{
    int a = 12;
    func( a );

    std::cout << "=================" << std::endl;

    func( 14 );

    std::cout << "=================" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I call `testRef()` in `testRef( int && param )` I presume that as far as param is rvalue reference than ravalue function will called (and yes, eternal recursion will happen). But lvalue function is called. Why?

Comment: The moment it has a name it's an lvalue.

Comment: huh! does it mean that I should use `std::move` in such cases?

Comment: Please move your answer from comments. Then I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it this way, you used `std::forward<T>` in `func`, so likewise, to make sure the parameter is forwarded as an Rvalue reference, you have to do the same in the recursive function:

```
void testRef(int && param)
{
    std::cout << "Rvalue reference" << std::endl;

    // Here's the thing I can't get. Why param is lvalue reference here??
    testRef( param );

    testRef(std::forward<int &&>(param)); // now it will stay an Rvalue reference
    testRef(std::move(param)); // make it an Rvalue reference
}
```

---

The reason we need `std::forward` or `std::move` is because `param` is of type `int&&` which is an lvalue (i.e. an rvalue reference parameter is an lvalue expression when you use it).

Behind the scenes these templates will eventually perform a `static_cast<int &&>` which yields an xvalue expression (which is also classified as an rvalue expression.) An xvalue expression binds to rvalue reference parameters.

This can be seen by looking at [Clang's syntax tree](https://godbolt.org/z/0B8kOz) for the following function:

```
             rvalue reference parameter (which binds to rvalue expressions)
             vvvvvvvvvvv
void testRef(int&& param)
{
    //std::move(param);

                        lvalue expression of type int&&
                        vvvvv
    static_cast<int &&>(param);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    xvalue expression 
    (considered an rvalue expression which binds to rvalue reference parameters) 
}
```

Abstract syntax tree for the function above:

```
TranslationUnitDecl
`-FunctionDecl <line:3:1, line:7:1> line:3:6 testRef 'void (int &&)'
  |-ParmVarDecl <col:14, col:21> col:21 used param 'int &&'
  `-CompoundStmt <line:4:1, line:7:1>
    `-CXXStaticCastExpr <line:6:5, col:30> 'int' xvalue static_cast<int &&> <NoOp>
      `-DeclRefExpr <col:25> 'int' lvalue ParmVar 0x55a692bb0a90 'param' 'int &&'
```

A shorthand way of explaining that a reference parameter becomes an lvalue would be to say that when it has a name (id-expression) it is an lvalue.

Comment: I presume that `std::forward<T>` is necessary when function parameter is universal reference. Am I right that `std::move` is more appropriate for this case?

Comment: `std::move` clearly expresses the intent in this case. You want the parameter to be an Rvalue reference. `std::forward` expresses the intent that you might not know what it is but you want it to stay the same and match the relevant function. Better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48999182/1460794).

Comment: As @Sombrero Chicken said if I have reference name it's lvalue. This means that we know for sure that `param` in `void testRef(int && param)` if lvalue. This intents me to use `std::move`. Now everything is clear, great thanks

Comment: Just to make it clear: This is *not* how `std::forward` should be used. When you're in a non-generic context and you want to move, please just use `std::move`.