# Is forward<T> the same as forward<T&&>?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, perfect-forwarding

Looking at [the documentation for `std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward),

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t ) noexcept;
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t ) noexcept;
```

Both functions return `T&&`, which (correct me if I'm wrong) [collapses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360880/why-an-rvalue-reference-is-turned-into-lvalue-reference-by-a-universal-reference) to

- `T&` if `T` is an lvalue reference
- `T&&` if `T` is an rvalue reference, or if `T` is not a reference

For an arbitrary type `T` which may be a reference, does reference collapsing always cause `forward<T>` to do the same as `forward<T&&>`?

If so, is there any reason to use `forward<T&&>`?

Comment: AFAIK they should be the same but `forward<T>` requires two less keystrokes :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does reference collapsing always cause `forward<T>` to do the same as `forward<T&&>`?

Yes.

> [I]s there any reason to use `forward<T&&>`?

No.

Note that this is assuming that the only `forward`s in view are the two overloads you showed in `std::`.